# Any addins in excel to display scientfic notation as written

Tags: microsoft-excel

Are there any addins in excel to display scientfic notation as written?

I want to see 5 x 10^-23 instead of 5E-23

Comment: Can you just set the formatting of the cell to general or text?

Answer (score 1):

If:

1. you have a block of cells already formatted to *Scientific*
2. the cells have data rather than formulas

Hi-light the cells and run this small macro:

```
Sub PseudoScientific()
    Dim DQ As String, mesage As String
    Dim r As Range
    DQ = Chr(34)
    For Each r In Selection
        v = r.Text
        v = Replace(v, "E", " x 10^")
        mesage = DQ & v & DQ
        r.NumberFormat = mesage & ";" & mesage & ";" & mesage & ";"
    Next r
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

Comment: I am not going to use this because I dont like using macros on my spreadsheets but thank you for letting me know it is possible to do. It is nice to see that Excel can be customized uisng macros but I dont know hat Microsoft doesn't improve its capabilities as it is has a lot of potential for numerical computation. I am using Matlab more and more these days but I like excel very much.